# Are there any last-minute cheap Spain-domestic flights?

Tags: air-travel, budget, spain, short-notice, barcelona

I'm travelling alone to Barcelona airport (BCN). I would like to take a cheap round-trip flight from BCN to Madrid.

Is there any web-site or smartphone app that sells last-minute cheap Spanish domestic flights?
I'm one passenger and flexible with dates.

Comment: Wouldn't a train or a bus likely be cheaper? Or shouldn't you at least be checking those too!

Comment: I will seach them as well. I have asked about flights because this is the fastest way. Among these I'm searching for the cheapest flight. This is unrelated to train or bus. If there is last minute or special offer ticket to bus or train, i would love to here about them as well.

Comment: I am not sure if flying is the fastest way to travel from Barcelona to Madrid. The AVE train takes +- 3 hours from city center to city center. If you fly, you have to add checkin time, airport transfers and time to claim luggage.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I know there is no such website or app that allows to book last-minute cheap flights. So you have to use any of the well-known services. In particular, the flight trip between Barcelona and Madrid (or viceversa) is known as "puente aereo" (literally "aerial bridge") and in general the cheapest company that operates this route is [Vueling](http://vueling.com) (13 flights per day). Prices starts from 50-70 € but it depends on the schedule.

Also the high-speed train is a good option and the bus is the cheapest option.

Comment: what's the usual price and time span for each of them? flight, train, fast train, bus?

Comment: Flight 1 hour / from 30 € (one way offer), Fast train 3 hours 18-40 € (one way, depends on offers). Slow train is not convenient, because its price is similar to fast train and it takes more than 5 hours. Bus is about 50 (return ticket) and takes 4-5 hours.